# Required to store the Firebase Response in arraylist

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, retrofit, retrofit2

I am required to fetch the response mentioned below from firebase by its url. Not by using DatabaseReference or DataSnapshot class. Just by firebase realtime database url.

```
{
"Emily Aries": "199",
"First Last": "2",
"J J": "194",
"John Deniel": "198",
"Sec User": "3"
}
```

Here the names and its values are dynamic.This are the values that firebase url returns from specific node named "users". I am required to store names in Names arraylist and ids in ids arraylist.

Here I am attaching the snap of my firebase node structure alongwith code so far I have tried to implement.

**ApiInterface.java**

```
@GET("group_chat/Demo Group_2-g/users")
Call<JSONObject> groupUsers();
```

Snippet from implementation in my main class.

```
private void getGroupUsersName() {

    apiInterface  = ApiClient.createService(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<JSONObject> call = apiInterface.groupUsers();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JSONObject> call, retrofit2.Response<JSONObject> response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JSONObject> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

[image: Here, is the structure in firebase of "users" node]

Answer (score 0):

Use

> JsonObject

Class from Gson Lib Instead of

> JSONObject

```
 @GET("group_chat/Demo Group_2-g/users")
 Call<JsonObject> groupUsers();


call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
            JsonObject jsonObject=response.body();
            ArrayList<String> names=new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> ids =new ArrayList<>();
            for(Map.Entry<String,JsonElement> entry : jsonObject.entrySet()){
                names.add(entry.getKey());
                ids.add(jsonObject.get(entry.getKey()).getAsString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

hope it Works

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please mention the whole code in your solution. As I cannot understand the jsonObject instance you mentioned in your solution.

Comment: Thanks @Amrnoid. Stil facing the issue. The issue is: onFailure:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 1 path $